# Android studios throws error on drawable tag vector after upgrading to support library 24.2.1

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I upgraded my android studio's version and now I am using version 2.1.3, which I believe is the current version. The com.android.support:appcompat-v7 too has been upgraded to 24.2.0.

Everything works fine except for the navigation back arrow which keeps giving an error,
this is the error

```
  08-22 18:04:59.470 11403-11403/com.app.oues E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.app.oues, PID: 11403
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.oues/com.app.oues.Registration}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020014
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020014
                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:346)
```

This is the code calling the arrow on the tool bar

```
 final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

This is my grade

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.oues"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0' }
```

After reading around it, I added `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to the gradle but it doesn't work, the error keeps popping up. I would be grateful if somebody could help. Thanks

Comment: It cant find your abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml. Did you try using a different icon to see if it will work?

Comment: Is this happening only in your release version, or also in the debug version?

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with the version 24 appCompat libraries as well.  In my stack trace, down lower than the NotFoundException, I had an XmlPullParserException  with a cause of 'invalid drawable tag vector'.  Although make sure you vector drawable XML file is just in your 'drawable' source folder.  Also, I just used the (deprecated) getResources().getDrawable() call which seems to work.  I also had tried your 'ContextCompat' call but it didn't change anything.  My call is:

```
syncButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sync_timer_day));
```

This only seemed to affect API 19 devices (Did not test below that).  It worked on API 22, 23 and 24 devices (Did not test 20 or 21).

My fix was to roll back to 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1' (and other associated V 23 stuff).  Now tested OK in emulators for API 19, 22, 23, and 24.

It took some time to figure out how to support all the flavors, but this seemed to work.

My app Gradle.build file looks like the below, although I may have some things in there that are not actually needed, as I was trying everything from multiple posts (Made the mistake of changing more than one thing at a time I'm afraid).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'RaceTac'
            keyPassword 'clover99'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/Dave/Documents/Dev/AndroidKeyStore.jks')
            storePassword 'clover99'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hubbardsoftware.racetac"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 14
        versionName '1.05'
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        generatedDensities = []
    }

    // Needed for backward compatibility with Vector graphics
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Not sure this is a direct answer, but V 24 does seem to have some issues.